# Android - Failed to export application after signing apk(Eclipse)

Tags: android, eclipse, apk, adt

I'm very new to Android development. I signed the apk, but after that when I go to choose the location to export the apk, I clicked "Finish" and it says "Failed to export application". I don't know what's going on. How can I fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the error console. It should show you a problem. It is likely that you are missing a library, etc.

Comment: I checked the console and it doesn't say anything. All I see is the MD5 and SHA1 fingerprints code

Comment: There are many reasons why export fails. Try to clean your project and restart Eclipse. Check all libraries and dependencies. If all this does not help, it is difficult to guess without knowing your complete project.

Comment: So I cleaned the project and restarted Eclipse. I tried exporting the signed apk again, and afterwards, when I clicked "Finish", a popup box came up that said, "Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1"